# localStorage is null in Chrome Mobile

Tags: javascript, android, google-chrome

My error reporting software is catching JS Web Storage (localStorage and sessionStorage) failures that are consistently on Android devices running Chrome mobile. I am not able to reproduce this error on my own Android device.

The specific error is:
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'setItem' of null` 
which is caught after I attempt to run
`localStorage.setItem("storageTest","storageTest")`

Any ideas or at other experiences with this problem are greatly appreciated.

Comment: Have you opened the stealth mode of the browser？

Comment: @toams7 I also have exact same problem in my website visited from Android Chrome Mobile. How did you solve yours?

Comment: @Sallu I wasn't able to solve the problem, so I built a storage module that attempts to use to web storage but uses cookies as a fallback. Cookies have a size limit, and because my application stores large amounts of JSON locally, my fallback has to save multiple cookies and combine them to read a given document. Here it is if you'd like to use it: https://gist.github.com/minicreative/8e6bb076907c9b880950b1455f60d10e (written for Angular but easily adapted as you need).

Comment: Cool. thanks a lot. Will check it out. My issue is that my data is also over 4k so cookies wont work.

Answer (score 2):

i think you need to enable dom storage in your android application

```
WebSettings settings = webView.getSettings();
settings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Comment: Thanks for you response - unfortunately this problem isn't happening in an Android application we have access to, it's happening in the Chrome browser for Android.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @Anil, this is the correct answer: Solved issue by enabling the DOM storage.

**Kotlin :**

```kotlin
val settings = webView.settings
settings.domStorageEnabled = true
```